# Proof of $\sup \epsilon x = \epsilon \sup x$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Suppose S is a non empty set of real numbers, and suppose S is bounded above, and that $\epsilon > 0$, Prove $\sup \epsilon x$ = $\epsilon\sup x$

My take so far:

$sup S = B$, then $B$ is an upper bound of $S$, $x \le B$ Let $T = {x:x \in S}$ and since $\epsilon > 0, \epsilon x \le \epsilon B$. Thus $T$ is bounded above by $\epsilon B$ and $\sup T = C$. Now we have to show that $C = \epsilon B$. Since $\epsilon B$ is an upper bound for $T$ and $C$ is $\sup=T$, $C \le \epsilon B$

and from here, I can't figure it out how to prove $\epsilon B \le C$? Because I'm assuming I have to show that $C = \epsilon B$ in order to finish this proof. Am I correct??

Comment: Use a \ before sup so that it renders as a command as so: $\sup$.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow you argument.  What you need to do is :

Comment: I think you meant $T=\{\varepsilon x: x \in S\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I can't follow your argument.

What you need to do is;

1 Define the set T as the image of S after multiplying each point by eps.

2  Show that if B is an upper bound of S, then C=epsB is an upper bound of T.

3   Show that T is non-empty and has an upper bound, so supT exists.

4 Show that supT = C, for in supT < C, then there would be an element y in T which corresponds to some element x in S such that x=y/eps < B, so we could find another value between y/eps and B which maps into T but then would be bigger than C.  Hence C=supT.

Hope that helps.